Edge selection highlight not working
After updating to 4.1 I stopped seeing selected edges when more than one is selected.
In this gif you can see I am selecting 3 edges. The first one behaves as usual, but when selecting the second and third one, the previously selected stops being highlighted, although is still selected otherwise I could't move all 3 at once.
I have a RTX 3090 with up to date drivers if it helps to discard visual glitches

https://ibb.co/q1K2q77
Anyone else?
